# Simple PHP error: syntax error, unfinished class declaration

Tags: php, oop, syntax-error

I get two errors and I dont know how to fix this.

I get the error "syntax error, unfinished class declaration" at the line:

```
private $language;
```

I get "syntax error, unexpected 'public', expecting 'EOF'" at the line:

```
public function getCurrencies()
```

This is the whole code:

```
class Driver extends Driver{

public static $url = "http://www.com/";
/* The method of posting data to the website */
public static $method = "GET";
/* The part of the url extending the domain name until the search term */
public static $url_searchbase = "search/searchresults.aspx?N=0&Ntt=";
/* The part of the url entailing the search term, deifining additional paramters */
public static $url_searchtail = "&Ntk=Primary&i=0&sw=n&ps=9999&pn=1";
private $currency;
private $language;
/* Allowed currencies */
$currencies = array("USD", "CAD");
/* Allowed languages */
$languages = array("ENU");

function __construct($currency, $language){
    if(setCurrency($currency) AND setLanguage($language)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        trigger_error("Currency '". $currency ."' or Language '". $language ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/*
 * Return an array of allowed currencies
 */
public function getCurrencies(){
    return $currencies;
}

/*
 * Set the currency
 */
function setCurrency($currency){
    if(in_array($currency, $this->$currencies)
    {
        $this->$currency = $currency;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        trigger_error("Currency '". $currency ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/*
 * Return an array of allowed languages
 */
public function getLanguages(){
    return $languages;
}

/*
 * Set the language
 */
public function setLanguage($language){
        if(in_array($language, $this->$languages)
    {
        $this->$language = $language;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        trigger_error("Language '". $language ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class Driver extends Driver` makes no sense. I think you got one of the names wrong.

Also, you cannot put real code outside of a function.

Move

```
/* Allowed currencies */
$currencies = array("USD", "CAD");
/* Allowed languages */
$languages = array("ENU");
```

into your `__construct()` function and use `$this->var` instead of `$var`.

In `if(in_array($currency, $this->$currencies)` there's missing a closing `)`.

Same for `if(in_array($language, $this->$languages)`

You are also accessing the member vars in an incorrect way. You need to use `$this->var` instead of `$this->$var` which would access the member variable whose *name* is stored in `$var`.

Comment: The comment about the array outside of a function was also very helpful, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

You had 4 errors:

1. Your variables $currencies and $languages had no scope.  You need to declare if they are public, private or protected.
2. Your class extends itself, this is not possible, I think you need to remove the extends Driver line.
3. You had missing closing brackets on your in_array functions (lines 39 and 60)
4. You were missing a closing brace } for your Class.  **EDIT:** *This was caused when pasting the code in stackoverflow.*

Fixed Code:

```
<?php
class Driver{

    public static $url = "http://www.com/";
    /* The method of posting data to the website */
    public static $method = "GET";
    /* The part of the url extending the domain name until the search term */
    public static $url_searchbase = "search/searchresults.aspx?N=0&Ntt=";
    /* The part of the url entailing the search term, deifining additional paramters */
    public static $url_searchtail = "&Ntk=Primary&i=0&sw=n&ps=9999&pn=1";
    private $currency;
    private $language;
    /* Allowed currencies */
    public $currencies = array("USD", "CAD");
    /* Allowed languages */
    public $languages = array("ENU");

    function __construct($currency, $language){
        if(setCurrency($currency) AND setLanguage($language)){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            trigger_error("Currency '". $currency ."' or Language '". $language ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Return an array of allowed currencies
     */
    public function getCurrencies(){
        return $currencies;
    }

    /*
     * Set the currency
     */
    function setCurrency($currency){
        if(in_array($currency, $this->$currencies))
        {
            $this->$currency = $currency;
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            trigger_error("Currency '". $currency ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Return an array of allowed languages
     */
    public function getLanguages(){
        return $languages;
    }

    /*
     * Set the language
     */
    public function setLanguage($language){
            if(in_array($language, $this->$languages))
        {
            $this->$language = $language;
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            trigger_error("Language '". $language ."' not supported.", E_USER_ERROR);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point 4 (the missing `}`) was only caused when pasting the code into stackoverflow. The `}` is there, just not in the code block.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Matt, I didn't check the source of the message in this case.  I'll leave it in so your comment still makes sense.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Set the currency
 */
function setCurrency($currency){
if(in_array($currency, $this->$currencies)
```

is missing a closing `)`, and the same goes for `setLanguage(..)`

Also `class Driver extends Driver` doesn't make any sense and should just be `class Driver`

Comment: Thanks for your help, sometimes I get overwhelmed when I start coding again after years of absence. I have "class Driver_Allied extends Driver", extending the own class is of course nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes:

1. You need to use `private` (or one of the other visibility options) for your `$currencies` and `$languages` class instance arrays.
2. Your `setCurrency` and `setLanguage` methods are missing a closing parenthesis on the first `if(in_array(` line.

Also, are you intending to extend a class called driver with a class called driver? (I very much suspect you just want to use `class Driver {`.)

Comment: @Timothy No problems. Onwards and upwards. :-)